# Infinite extensions of "finite degree under $\mathbb{Q}$"

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

Consider an algebraic extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}$.

The degree $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ of $K$ is defined as the dimension of the extension considered as a vector space.

Now, let $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ be algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$.

My question is,

> Can we built an arbitrary algebraic extension $F$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ such
>   that $[\overline{\mathbb{Q}}:F]=n$, for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$? How?

Comment: No; see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8756/examples-of-algebraic-closures-of-finite-index.